# How to hide 'No Mail Accounts' popup when iPhone default Mail app has not setup(Not logged In)?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I tried to hide popup but didn't got success, So please provide suggestions to hide or remove 'No Mail Accounts' popup from device as well.

[image]

Comment: show your tried code

Comment: i dont have code, if you have then send

Comment: You can't hide it; it is presented by iOS. Show the code that results in this dialog being shown.